# Laravel 5 add nusoap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am unable to install nusoap to my existing laravel 5 application. Ive done the following:

Created a new Folder in App/Http/Controllers/ - namend "Soap" - and copied the libary into it.

use

```
composer dump-autoload
```

So i am able to use

```
use nusoap_client;
```

But i am always getting an error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\nusoap_client' not found
```

I thought that laravel automatically load all classes from the "app" directory, but how can i use it here?

Tried with:

```
 $wsdl = "test.xx/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try use App\Http\Controllers\Soap\nusoap_client as nusoap_client

Comment: Why haven't you installed the library via composer?

Comment: I have already done that (it was an answer here, and ill already accepted it) - but the user deleted it. Ill only checked for laravel packages for nusoap - now already works fine with the composer package. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add these lines to your controller:

```
include 'nusoap.php';
use nusoap_client;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simple way, you can add a backslash in front of `nusoap_client`, like this:

```
$client = new \nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
```